# Is it possible to read a file's modification date with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to read a file's modification date with Ruby? I have successfully opened a text file and captured the contents of the file with

```
File.open("test.txt", "r").each do |line|"
```

but it would be very useful to read the modification date of the file.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use [`mtime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-mtime):

```
File.mtime("testfile")
=> 2014-04-13 16:00:23 -0300
```

Comment: Hi! Is mtime OS agnostic?

Answer (score 27):

"Returns the modification time for the named file as a Time object."

```
File.mtime("testfile")   #=> Tue Apr 08 12:58:04 CDT 2003
```

[Check this.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-mtime)