# Get file's last modification date with Logstash

Tags: file, logstash, datecreated, datemodified

Is there a way for Logstash to get the date at which a file has been last modified?

In Linux, this would correspond to the `date -r` command.

Comment: I don't get the down vote. This is a genuine and precise question and I don't see how I could add more info to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash does not expose this by default, but you can do just about anything with a `ruby` filter.  A quick Google search find: [Is it possible to read a file's modification date with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580728/is-it-possible-to-read-a-files-modification-date-with-ruby)

Logstash does expose the name of the file as part of the event, so putting it together, we'd get:

```
ruby {
  code => 'event["mtime"] = File.mtime(event["path"])'
}
```

I've never tried this, so I might have missed something.